# How can I build a url with a named route?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravelcollective

I'm trying to generate a url link using a named route. For example, I have `http://myapp.com/{token}`. But, I had been using a lot of function with route but the result that I have is `http://myapp.com?token` instead of `http://myapp.com/token`.

What can I do?

The only way to generate the good url is using the function `url` without the name of url. For example: `url( '/reset', [$token])`. But in this case, I am not using the name of the route where that is what I would like to use.

Real problem:
I have a route like this:

```
// Password reset routes...
Route::get('reset/{token}', [
    'as' => 'password.reset',
    'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset'
]);
```

A blade template:

```
<a href="{{ url( '/reset', [$token]) }}">Click here to reset your password</a>
<br>
<a href="{{ url( route('password.reset', $token)) }}">Click here to reset your password</a>
<br>
{!! link_to_route('password.reset', 'Click here to reset your password', $token) !!}
<br>
<a href="{{ route('password.reset', $token) }}">Click here to reset your password</a>
```

The result is:

```
<a href="https://laravel51.app2/reset/72a560d23a1bf17eec336d07c169bd4c02d25e24ae3581977b4fa4aa4f4e3252">Click here to reset your password</a>
<br>
<a href="https://laravel51.app2/reset?72a560d23a1bf17eec336d07c169bd4c02d25e24ae3581977b4fa4aa4f4e3252">Click here to reset your password</a>
<br>
<a href="https://laravel51.app2/reset?72a560d23a1bf17eec336d07c169bd4c02d25e24ae3581977b4fa4aa4f4e3252">Click here to reset your password</a>
<br>
<a href="https://laravel51.app2/reset?72a560d23a1bf17eec336d07c169bd4c02d25e24ae3581977b4fa4aa4f4e3252">Click here to reset your password</a>
```

Comment: Per the docs, `route()`'s second parameter should be an array. `route('password.reset', ['token' => $token])`

Comment: I could notice that I have two differents routes with the same alias. That was my problem. After I renamed the routes, the function works well.

route('password.reset', [ 'token' => $token ])

    // Password reset routes...
    Route::get('reset/{token}', [
        'as' => 'password.reset',
        'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset'
    ]);
    Route::post('reset', [
        'as' => 'password.reset_post',
        'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset'
    ]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
route('password.reset', [ 'token' => $token ])
```

is what you need to write

Comment: I tried but It is not worked because it just add the token as a variable of url. 

https://laravel51.app2/reset?token=bf8880513474a02......

Comment: so you used different alias now for your routes? it worked?

Comment: Yes, I only needed to do that. The problem was that I had two different routes with the same name.